# Switching between Expo Apps Running on Android Emulator

Tags: react-native, android-emulator, expo

I am sorry for the trivial question!

While testing an Expo (react-native) app on Android Emulator, I need to switch to other apps, e.g. to the Contacts Manager to add a contact. Then, I need to go back to the Expo app to test something. How can I do that?

**I tried the following.**

1. Start the Expo app and play with it
2. Press the Home button
3. Start Contacts Manager

**I could NOT find a way to start the Expo app again.** I found an Expo icon in the list of apps. When I clicked on it, a screen with everything disabled, except "Open from Clipboard" appeared. The "Open from Clipboard" option seems to be for switching between different Expo apps. Anyway, when I clicked on it, I got the following error message.

Something went wrong. Could not load exp://switching/%20between%20Expo%20apps%20running%20on%20Android%20Emulator.

**Environment:**

1. Expo: 32.0.0
2. Android Emulator: API: 25 - Android 7.1.1 x86 - Nexus S

Thank you for your effort and time to help...

Answer (score 2):

Are you using a connection localhost? if yes, on the terminal, try to press 'a'.